# Azure Active Directory Federation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blockchain-workbench, sql-azure-federations

I want to create a federation between a couple of Azure accounts (Tenants).
The goal is that when signing into the Active Directory there will be only a couple of users that can sign in (users in the federation)
Users in the federation are adding guest users of their own but when using an application (In my example, application on the Blockchain workbench). All of the federation users could see all of the guest users (theirs and the other guest users that the other tenants added).

How can I do this?

Thanks